# pull out data from database and display in Gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity forms plugin, and I'm trying to display the categories as a drop down list in the form I have already created.

[image]

If required, please here's a link to [my website](http://www.martcircle.com)

I've been on this for too long, and no way out. Kindly help me out.

```html
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'populate_categories' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_1', 'populate_categories' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'populate_categories' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_1', 'populate_categories' );
function populate_categories( $form ) {

    foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if ( $field->id != 1 ) {
            continue;
        }

        // you can add additional parameters here to alter the posts that are retrieved
        // more info: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
        $categories = get_categories ;

        $choices = array();

        foreach ( $categories as $categories ) {
            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $categories->name, 'value' => $categories->name );
        }

        // update 'Select a Post' to whatever you'd like the instructive option to be
        $field->placeholder = 'Category';
        $field->choices = $choices;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can dynamically generate drop downs for gravity forms using the syntax provided below in this link. You have to take control over the **functions.php** file of the theme to retrieve your output as per your requirement.

Here is the clear documentation provided and you can create in a simple manner using this methods. There are two methods available refer to it.

https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

If you face any problem with creation let me know we shall solve it.

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for help, sorry this reply is coming late, I made an urgent trip which kept the project on pause.  I followed the steps on the link you sent, but it didn't give me the list of my categories, maybe I aint doing it right. I've added the php codes I used on this post just in case you might want to take a look at it. THANKS AGAIN